# Error logging, in a smooth way

Tags: php, pdo

I've been reading on in particular 'error logging' And I have come up with the function 'error_log' which seem to be a good tool to use to handle the error logging. But how is the smoothest and best way to use it?

If I have a

```
try {
     //try a database connection...

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");

}
```

This would log the error in the my-errors.log file. But what If I sometime need to change the position of where the file is, a new folder, or something. If I have tons of files I need to change them all.

Now I started of thinking to use a variable to set the path to the error log. Sure that could work, but what If I want to use the error_log in a function or class method? Then I would need to set the variable as global, but that is considered bad practise! But what If I shouldn't use the function deep in a class, wouldn't that also be considered bad practise? What is a good solution here?

```
<?php

function legit() {
    try {
        if (1 == 1) {
            throw new Exception('There was an error here');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception('throw the error to the try-catch outside the function...');
    }

}

try {
    legit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'error here' . $e->getMessage();

    //log it
}
```

This is an example of what I was talking about above (Not having the logging deep in a class/function... Is it a good way?)

Furtheron:

I am not quite sure how I should use the Exceptions in general. Let's say I want to do a INSERT to a database with SQL inside a method, would I use a try/catch and then rethrow the exception if it fails? Is that considered good practise? Examples please.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in error logging, using the `log_errors` configuration directive, and optionally `trigger_error` to send them to the logs? That sends them to your web server's error logs. And you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: Well depending on the case I would like to use different methods of logging, email, database, etc.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Firstly, I'd like to commend you for looking at the standard error methods within PHP.  Unfortunately `error_log` has some limitations as you found out.

This is a long answer, read on to find out about:

1. Errors

   - Logging the error directly vs `trigger_error` and `set_error_handler`
   - Where good errors go bad - Fatal Errors.
2. Exceptions

   - SPL
   - What to do with them?
3. Code

   - Setup
   - Usage

**TL;DR** Use `trigger_error` for raising errors and `set_error_handler` for logging them.

1. Errors
   =========

When things don't go as expected in your program, you will often want to raise an error so that someone or something is notified.  An error is for a situation where the program may continue, but something noteworthy, possibly harmful or erroneous has occurred.  At this point many people want to log the error immediately with their logging package of choice.  I believe this is exactly the wrong thing to do.  I recommend using `trigger_error` to raise the error so that it can be handled with a callback set by `set_error_handler`.  Lets compare these options:

**Logging the error directly**

So, you have chosen your logging package.  Now you are ready to spread the calls to your logger wherever an error occurs in your code.  Lets look at a single call that you might make (I'll use a similar logger to the one in Jack's answer):

`Logger::getLogger('standard')->error('Ouch, this hurts');`

What do you need in place to run this code?

```
    Class:  Logger
    Method: getLogger
    Return: Object with method 'error'
```

These are the dependencies that are required to use this code.  Everyone who wants to re-use this code will have to provide these dependencies.  This means that a standard PHP configuration will no longer be sufficient to re-use your code.  With the best case, using Dependency Injection you still require a logger object to be passed into all of your code that can emit an error.

Also, in addition to whatever the code is responsible for, it also has responsibility for logging the error.  This goes against the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

We can see that **logging the error directly is bad**.

**trigger_error to the rescue**

PHP has a function called [`trigger_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) which can be used to raise an error just like the standard functions do.  The error levels that you use with it are defined in the [error level constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php).  As a user you must use one of the user errors: `E_USER_ERROR`, `E_USER_WARNING` or the default value `E_USER_NOTICE` (other error levels are reserved for the standard functions etc.).  Using a standard PHP function to raise the error allows the code to be re-used with any standard PHP installation!  Our code is no longer responsible for logging the error (only making sure that it is raised).

Using `trigger_error` we only perform half of the error logging process (raising the error) and save the responsibility of responding to the error for the error handler which will be covered next.

**Error Handler**

We set a custom error handler with the [`set_error_handler`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function (see the code setup).  This custom error handler replaces the standard PHP error handler that normally logs messages in the web server error log depending on the PHP configuration settings.  We can still use this standard error handler by returning `false` within our custom error handler.

The custom error handler has a single responsibility: to respond to the error (including any logging that you want to do).  Within the custom error handler you have full access to the system and can run any sort of logging that you want.  Virtually any logger that uses the Observer design pattern will be ok (I'm not going to go into that as I believe it is of secondary importance).  This should allow you to hook in new log observers to send the output to where you need it.

You have complete control to do what you like with the errors in a single maintainable part of your code.  The error logging can now be changed quickly and easily from project to project or within a single project from page to page.  Interestingly even `@` suppressed errors make it to the custom error handler with an `errno` of 0 which if the [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) mask is respected should not be reported.

**When Good Errors go Bad - Fatal Errors**

It is not possible to continue from certain errors.  The following error levels can not be handled from a custom error handler: `E_ERROR`, `E_PARSE`, `E_CORE_ERROR`, `E_CORE_WARNING`, `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, `E_COMPILE_WARNING`.  When these sorts of errors are triggered by a standard function call the custom error handler is skipped and the system shuts down.  This can be generated by:

`call_this_function_that_obviously_does_not_exist_or_was_misspelt();`

This is a **serious** mistake!  It is impossible to recover from, and the system is about to shut down.  Our only choice is to have a [`register_shutdown_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) deal with the shutdown.  However this function is executed whenever a script completes (successful, as well as unsuccessful).  Using this and [`error_get_last`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) some basic information can be logged (the system is almost shutdown at this point) when the last error was a fatal error.  It can also be useful to send the correct status code and show an Internal Server Error type page of your choosing.

2. Exceptions
   =============

Exceptions can be dealt with in a very similar way to basic errors.  Instead of `trigger_error` an exception will be thrown by your code (manually with `throw new Exception` or from a standard function call).  Use [`set_exception_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to define the callback you want to use to handle the exception with.

**SPL**

The Standard PHP Library (SPL) provides [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php).  They are my preferred way of raising exceptions because like `trigger_error` they are a standard part of PHP which does not introduce extra dependencies to your code.

**What to do with them?**

When an exception is thrown there are three choices that can be made:

1. Catch it and fix it (the code then continues as if nothing bad happened).
2. Catch it, append useful information and re-throw it.
3. Let it bubble up to a higher level.

At each level of the stack these choices are made.  Eventually once it bubbles up to the highest level the callback you set with `set_exception_handler` will be executed.  This is where your logging code belongs (for the same reasons as the error handling) rather than spread throughout `catch` statements in your code.

## **3. Code**

### Setup

**Error Handler**

```
function errorHandler($errno , $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
    // Perform your error handling here, respecting error_reporting() and
    // $errno.  This is where you can log the errors.  The choice of logger
    // that you use is based on your preference.  So long as it implements
    // the observer pattern you will be able to easily add logging for any
    // type of output you desire.
}

$previousErrorHandler = set_error_handler('errorHandler');
```

**Exception Handler**

```
function exceptionHandler($e)
{
    // Perform your exception handling here.
}

$previousExceptionHandler = set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');
```

**Shutdown Function**

```
function shutdownFunction()
{
    $err = error_get_last();
    
    if (!isset($err))
    {
        return;
    }

    $handledErrorTypes = array(
        E_USER_ERROR      => 'USER ERROR',
        E_ERROR           => 'ERROR',
        E_PARSE           => 'PARSE',
        E_CORE_ERROR      => 'CORE_ERROR',
        E_CORE_WARNING    => 'CORE_WARNING',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR   => 'COMPILE_ERROR',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'COMPILE_WARNING');
    
    // If our last error wasn't fatal then this must be a normal shutdown.  
    if (!isset($handledErrorTypes[$err['type']]))
    {
        return;
    }
    
    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    }

    // Perform simple logging here.
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdownFunction');
```

### Usage

**Errors**

```
// Notices.
trigger_error('Disk space is below 20%.', E_USER_NOTICE);
trigger_error('Disk space is below 20%.'); // Defaults to E_USER_NOTICE

// Warnings.
fopen('BAD_ARGS'); // E_WARNING fopen() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given
trigger_error('Warning, this mode could be dangerous', E_USER_WARNING);

// Fatal Errors.    
// This function has not been defined and so a fatal error is generated that
// does not reach the custom error handler.
this_function_has_not_been_defined();
// Execution does not reach this point.

// The following will be received by the custom error handler but is fatal.
trigger_error('Error in the code, cannot continue.', E_USER_ERROR);
// Execution does not reach this point.
```

**Exceptions**

Each of the three choices from before are listed here in a generic way, fix it, append to it and let it bubble up.

1 Loggable. Let it bubble up:

```
// Don't catch it. 
// Either it will be caught by error handler
// Or PHP will log it as a fatal error
```

2 Fixable:

```
try
{
    $value = code_that_can_generate_exception();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // We decide to emit a notice here (a warning could also be used).
    trigger_error('We had to use the default value instead of ' .
                  'code_that_can_generate_exception\'s', E_USER_NOTICE);
    // Fix the exception.
    $value = DEFAULT_VALUE;
}

// Code continues executing happily here.
```

3 Append:

Observe below how the `code_that_can_generate_exception()` does not know about `$context`.  The catch block at this level has more information which it can append to the exception if it is useful by rethrowing it.

```
try
{
    $context = 'foo';
    $value = code_that_can_generate_exception();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Raise another exception, with extra information and the existing
    // exception set as the previous exception. 
    throw new Exception('Context: ' . $context, 0, $e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a very good post, I actually found the set_error_handler a while ago, but this made the topic clearer. About the exceptions how would you do it? Should I catch the errors in all the methods in a class or just let the higher level set_exception_handler fix it? :)

Comment: I only catch it when I can do something useful.  You'll know the level where you can do something useful when you see it.  If you are in doubt let it bubble up.  The set exception handler won't be able to fix an exception, but may be appropriate for exceptions that your code just cannot function with.  For an example: I'd expect the database to throw exceptions and methods that used the database to catch them (except perhaps for a DB connection failure which could be handled by the set_exception_handler).  It really does depend on the individual situation though.

Comment: Although this answer was written in 2012, I still found it very useful. Thanks a lot for making it very clear @paul

Comment: @Paul Great answer!

Answer (score 37):

It has been requested to make this answer more applicable to a larger audience, so here goes.

**Preamble**

Error handling is usually not the first thing you will want to think about when writing an application; as an indirect result it gets bolted on as the need arises. However, it doesn't have to cost much to leverage existing mechanisms in PHP either.

It's a fairly lengthy article, so I've broken it down into logical sets of text.

**Triggering errors**

Within PHP there are two distinct ways for errors to get triggered:

1. Errors from PHP itself (e.g. using undefined variables) or internal functions (e.g. `imagecreatefromjpeg` could not open a file),
2. Errors triggered by user code using [`trigger_error`](http://sg.php.net/trigger_error),

These are usually printed on your page (unless [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) is switched off or [`error_reporting`](http://sg.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is zero), which should be standard for production machines unless you write perfect code like me ... moving on); those errors can also be captured, giving you a glimpse into any hitch in the code, by using [`set_error_handler`](http://sg.php.net/set_error_handler) explained later.

**Throwing exceptions**

Exceptions are different from errors in three main ways:

1. The code that handles them may be far removed from the place where they are thrown from. The variable state at the origin must be explicitly passed to the Exception constructor, otherwise you only have the stack trace.
2. The code between the exception and the catch is skipped entirely, whereas after an error occurs (and it was not fatal) the code still continues.
3. They can be extended from the main `Exception` class; this allows you to catch and handle specific exceptions but let others bubble down the stack until they're caught by other code. See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

An example of throwing exceptions is given later on.

**Handling errors**

Capturing and handling errors is pretty straightforward by registering an error handler, e.g.:

```
function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = 'unknown', $errline = 0, array $errcontext = array())
{
    // $errcontext is very powerful, it gives you the variable state at the point of error; this can be a pretty big variable in certain cases, but it may be extremely valuable for debugging
    // if error_reporting() returns 0, it means the error control operator was used (@)
    printf("%s [%d] occurred in %s:%d\n%s\n", $errstr, $errno, $errfile, $errline, print_r($errcontext, true));

    // if necessary, you can retrieve the stack trace that led up to the error by calling debug_backtrace()

    // if you return false here, the standard PHP error reporting is performed
}

set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

For kicks, you can turn all the errors into an [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) as well by registering the following error handler (PHP >= 5.1):

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

**Handling exceptions**

In most cases you handle exceptions as close as possible to the code that caused it to allow for backup plans. For instance, you attempt to insert a database record and a primary key constraint exception is thrown; you can recover by updating the record instead (contrived as most databases can handle this by themselves). Some exceptions just can't be handled locally, so you want those to cascade down. Example:

```
function insertRecord($user, $name)
{
    try {
        if (true) {
            throw new Exception('This exception should not be handled here');
        }
        // this code is not executed
        $this->db->insert('users', array('uid' => $user, 'name' => $name));
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // attempt to fix; an exception thrown here will cascade down
        throw $e; // rethrow exception

        // since PHP 5.3.0 you can also nest exceptions
        throw new Exception("Could not insert '$name'", -1, $e);
    } catch (WhatEverException $e) {
        // guess what, we can handle whatever too
    }
}
```

**The slippery exception**

So what happens when you don't catch an exception anywhere? You can catch that too by using [`set_exception_handler`](http://sg.php.net/set_exception_handler).

```
function my_exception_handler(Exception $exception)
{
    // do your stuff here, just don't throw another exception here
}

set_exception_handler('my_exception_handler');
```

This is not encouraged unless you have no meaningful way to handle the exception anywhere in your code.

**Logging the error / exception**

Now that you're handling the error you have to log it somewhere. For my example, I use a project that Apache ported from Java to PHP, called [LOG4PHP](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/). There are others, but it illustrates the importance of a flexible logging facility.

It uses the following concepts:

1. [Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/loggers.html) - named entities that perform logging upon your behalf; they can be specific to a class in your project or shared as a common logger,
2. [Appenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders.html) - each log request can be sent to one or more destinations (email, database, text file) based on predefined conditions (such as log level),
3. Levels - logs are classified from debug messages to fatal errors.

Basic usage to illustrate different message levels:

```
Logger::getLogger('main')->info('We have lift off');
Logger::getLogger('main')->warn('Rocket is a bit hot');
Logger::getLogger('main')->error('Houston, we have a problem');
```

Using these concepts you can model a pretty powerful logging facility; for example, without changing above code, you can implement the following setup:

1. Collect all debug messages in a database for developers to look at; you might disable this on the production server,
2. Collect warnings into a daily file that you might email at the end of the day,
3. Have immediate emails sent on fatal errors.

Comment: Hahaha nice Houston reference :P

Comment: @Jack very complete answer.  on the same topic of error handling (albeit in c++) you closed down one of my questions as being "vague", without the help or courtesy of any explanation or indication as to how to make it less offensive to you and yours.  i have edited it and request your support reviewing it (if you close it, you should be the first to analyze if it is NOW ok).  i would greatly appreciate your support.  ps: very cool product your muvee, i will get in touch regarding that in the close future! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609104/catch-mysql-error-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Define it, then use it :)

```
define('ERRORLOG_PATH', '/var/tmp/my-errors.log');

error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, ERRORLOG_PATH);
```

Alternatively just make the third parameter of `error_log` optional, defaulting it to the path you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you still need a custom way of handling logs (i.e. you don't want to use standard `trigger_error()`), I'd recommend looking at Zend_Log (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.overview.html) for these reasons:

1. this can be used as a standalone component, ZF is not a full-stack framework. You may copy only Zend_Loader and Zend_Log namespaces , instantiate Zend_Loader and use it. See below:

   ```
   require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');

   $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

   $logger = new Zend_Log();    
   $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('php://output');

   $logger->addWriter($writer);    
   $logger->log('Informational message', Zend_Log::INFO);
   ```
2. You were offered many logging libraries, but I believe that Zend team (founders of PHP lang) know what they do
3. You may use any writers (database, STDOUT - see above, file, whatever, you may customize it to write your own to post log messages to a web service even)
4. log levels
5. may change log format (but the one that is out-of-box is great to my mind). The above example with standard formatter will produce something like this:

> 2012-05-07T23:57:23+03:00 INFO (6): Informational message

5. just read the reference, it may be configured to catch php errors

Comment: I have used the Zend_log in other projects, and of some reason I wasn't really pleased about it, but thanks anyway for your reply

Comment: @John: there is also [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) and  [apache log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/) - probably that's helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition, for error logging (and in fact all logging) I would use event dispatcher, in a way that symfony framework does.

Take a look at this sf component (its very lightweight dependency, entire framework is not required, there are maybe 3 relevant php classes and 2 interfaces)

https://github.com/symfony/EventDispatcher

this way you can create dispatcher somewhere in your application bootstrap:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

$dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();

//register listeners
$dispatcher->addListener('application.log', function (Event $event) {
    //do anything you want
});
```

Then you can raise an event in any place of your code by something like

```
$dispatcher->dispatch(new GenericEvent('application.log', array('message' => 'some log', 'priority' => 'high'));
```

Of course you can subclass event class with your own events:

```
class LogEvent extends GenericEvent {
    public function __construct($message, $priority = 'INFO') {
        parent::__construct('application.log', array('message'=>$message,'priority'=>$priority));
    }
    public function getMessage() { return $this->getArgument('message'); }
    public function getPriority() { return $this->getArgument('priority'); }
}

// now raising LogEvent is much cleaner:
$dispatcher->dispatch(new LogEvent('some log'));
```

This will also allow you to create more customized events like ExceptionEvent

```
 class ExceptionEvent extends GenericEvent {
    public function __construct(Exception $cause) {
        parent::__construct('exception.event', array('cause' => $cause));
    }
 }
```

And handle them accordingly.

### Advantages

- you separate logging logic from your application
- you can easily add and remove loggers in runtime
- you can easily register as many loggers you want (i.e. DebugLogger which logs everything into text file, ErrorLogger which logs only errors to error_log, CriticalLogger which logs only critical errors on production environment and sends them by email to administrator, etc.)
- you can use event dispatcher for more things than just logging (in fact for every job for which observer pattern is appropriate)
- actual logger becomes nothing more than 'implementation detail' - it's so easy to replace that it doesn't matter where your logs go - you will be able to replace log destination at any time without having to refactor names of your methods, or changing anything in code.
- it will be easy to implement complex log routing logic or globally change log format (by configuring loggers)
- everything becomes even more flexible if you use dependency injection for both listeners (loggers) and dispatcher (into classes that notifies log event)

### Actual Logging

As someone already stated, I would advice to go with out-of-the-box library, like mentioned Monolog, Zend_Log or log4php, there is probably no reason to code these things by hand (and the last thing you want is broken error logger!)

PS: Treat code snippets as pseudo-code, I didn't test them. Details can be found in docs of mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP way of handling errors is not flexible enough for you (e.g. sometimes you want to log to database, sometimes to file, sometimes whatever else), you need to use / create a custom PHP logging framework.

You can browse through the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341154/php-logging-framework or just go and give the top choice, [KLogger](https://github.com/katzgrau/KLogger), a try. I am not sure, though, if it supports custom destinations for logging. But at the very least, it's a small and easy-to-read class and you should be able to extend it further for your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Tom vand der Woerdt's logging solution, simplest and most effective for your requirements.

As for the other question:

You do not need to catch / rethrow the exception inside the function unless there is a specific kind of exception you have a solution for.

Somewhat simplistic example:

```
define('ERRORLOG_PATH', '/var/tmp/my-errors.log');
function do_something($in)
{
    if (is_good($in))
    {
        try {
            return get_data($in);
        } catch (NoDataException $e) {
            // Since it's not too big a deal that nothing
            // was found, we just return false.
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArguementException('$in is not good');
    }
}

function get_data($data)
{
    if (!is_int($data))
    {
        InvalidArguementException('No');
    }
    $get = //do some getting.
    if (!$get)
    {
        throw new NoDataException('No data was found.');
    } else {
        return $get;
    }
}

try {
   do_something('value');
} catch (Exception $e) {
   error_log($e->getMessage(), 3, ERRORLOG_PATH);
   die ('Something went wrong :(');
}
```

Here you'd only catch the `NoDataException` because you have some other logic to sort that out, all other errors fall though to the first catch and are handled by the top catch because all thrown exceptions must at some point in their hierarchy inherit from `Exception`.

Obviously if you throw an `Exception` again (outside the initial `try {}` or in the top `catch {}`) your script will exit with an Uncaught Exception error and error logging is lost.

If you wanted to go all the way, you could also implement a custom error handling function using `set_error_handler()` and put your logging in there too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two challenges to meet. The first is to be flexible in logging to different channels. In this case you should take a look at for example [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog).

The second challenge is to weave in that logging into your application. Imho the best case is no to use logging explicitly. Here for example [aspect orientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_software_development) comes in handy. A good sample is [flow3](http://flow3.typo3.org/).

But this is more a bird's eye view on the problem...

Answer (score 0):

I use my own function which allows me to write multiple types of log files by setting or changing the second parameter.

I get past the conceptual questions you are asking about "what is the right way" to do it,  by including the log function in a library of functions that I consider "native" to my development projects.
That way I can consider those functions to be just part of "MY" php core,  like `date()` or `time()`

In this basic version of dlog,  I also handle arrays.  while I originally used this to log errors, I ended up using it for other 'quick and dirty' short term tracking such as logging the times that the code entered a certain section,  and user logins,  etc.

```
function dlog($message,$type="php-dlog")
{
    if(!is_array($message)  )
        $message=trim($message);
    error_log(date("m/d/Y h:i:s").":".print_r($message,true)."\n",3, "/data/web/logs/$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]-$type.log");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most error loggers and exception loggers are useless to most people because they haven't got access to the log files.

I prefer to use a custom error handler and a custom exception handler and have those, during production, log errors directly to the database if the system is running on a database.

During development, when display_errors are set, they log nothing as all errors gets raised in the browser.

And as a side note to that: Don't make your custom error handler throw exceptions! It's a really bad idea. It can cause bugs in the buffer handler and in some of the extensions. Also some core PHP functions like fopen() causes a warning or notice on failure, these should be dealt with accordingly and should not halt the application has an exception would do.

The mention of having the error handler throwing exceptions in the PHP documentation is a note bug.

Comment: 1. I have doubts on the "most people" statement. 2. Anyway, you can always tell PHP write logs to whatever file you wish. 3. Database is error-prone itself and thus unreliable storage for the error logging. 4. Your idea of handling exceptions is utterly wrong. It's exception can be caught instead of halting script, while there is no such mechanism for the errors. Custom handling is a great idea in general, but you implementation and reasoning is out of question.

Comment: File logging relies heavily on the users write permissions on the host and access to those files. And yes, while a database might fault, it is still one of the easiest places to log errors and exceptions and you can just as easily validate your access to the database. By your reasoning we should be using the database at all whereas most PHP web applications highly depend on the database and access to it, so if the application is using a database it makes good sense to log to it as well. About errors throwing exceptions, you don't know what you're talking about. Like I said, it can cause bugs.

Comment: By my reasoning every medium have to be used for it's purpose. **Most important fatal errors would be logged in error log anyway** - so, there is just no point in bothering with 2 mediums. For this statement on exception you have a proof code to reproduce, I believe. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As KNL states, which is quite right, but unfortunately as of yet undocumented, having errors throwing exceptions is not something recommended by the PHP developers and someone made a mistake in the documentation. It can indeed cause bugs with many extensions so don't do it.

This has already been debated on #PHP on irc.

The "However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with ErrorException."  on http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php is going to be removed.