# Whether error_reporting(0) in php prevent hacking

Tags: php, security, xss, sql-injection

Whether using error_reporting(0) in php script will prevent hacking using SQLi or XSS by not reporting error?

Comment: definitely not preventing **XSS**, no way :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `error_reporting(0)` is plain dangerous; you're hiding warnings that could give vital clues to shaky coding. At the same time it won't prevent SQL injection issues or xss.

My advice: set `error_reporting(-1)` at all times and either log all errors using `error_log` or write a [custom error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10476589#10476589) using `set_error_handler()` to handle the errors without showing them on the page. During development you should always enable `display_errors` as well.

Note that nothing but good coding practices and proper testing can mitigate hacking, but preventing it altogether takes even more. Adopt defensive programming or perhaps ask [Bernstein](http://cr.yp.to/djb.html) to tutor you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

By doing error_reporting(0) you only hide the errors from the user. In some cases it may be helpful to minimize hacking but not the XSS attacks for sure.