# Can you use an IF statement on an object?

Tags: php

My apologies if I misstate something or use an incorrect term.  But I was trying to figure out how to use an if statement on an object.

This works just fine and as I understand it, the @ suppresses errors.

```
if (@mail("$receiver_email", "$subject", "$message", "$headers")) { }
```

However If I do this it fails:

```
if (@$mail->send('email@gmail.com', "$receiver_email", "$subject", "$message")) {}
```

The irony is that the email goes through but the IF fails.  How can I fix the IF statement so it works properly?

Comment: $bla = $mail->send(); if ($bla) {} ? depends on what your send() method returns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use `@`. It's bad practice and better dealt with using error handling routines; see also: [Error logging, in a smooth way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10476589#10476589)

From your code I can only guess that your code is like this:

```
public function send($from, $to, $subject, $message)
{
    // your code here
}
```

If the function doesn't have a return value, it defaults to `null` and that evaluates to `false` which is why the IF "fails".

You should return a success value from your `send()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First: try to avoid @, it's generally a bad practice..

Why the if fails does not depend wether the sending was succesful. Only if the `mail()` function in whatever class `$mail` is actually returns something (like true or false) you can do something with this.

Since this is not a built-in PHP class, you should ask the authors of your class (or yourself, if you wrote it) to return true on success.

In short: this is not something you can fix, the person who wrote the `send` function can fix this.