# PHP - jquery dont get the post return when using class

Tags: php, jquery, post

here's my link_handler.php as a post method action.

```
require_once 'download_handler.php';

if ($_POST) {

    if (empty($_POST['link'])) {
        $mahar['success'] = false;
        $mahar['error'] = "you're not insert any link";
        echo json_encode($mahar); //work, show error string on #success
        exit();
    }

    $download = new Hijack($_POST['link']);
    $download->check_link();
    $download->execute();
    $mahar['success'] = $download->result['success']; // produce success(bool) = false
    $mahar['error'] = $download->result['error']; // produce error string : there's some error on parsing some stuff
    echo json_encode($mahar); //not work show nothing on #success
}
```

and this is my jquery syntax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#go").click(function() {
    $("#success").fadeOut();
        $.post('link_handler.php', {link: $("#url").val()},
        function(mahar) {
            if (mahar.success) {
                $("#success").html(mahar.link);
            } else {
                $("#success").html(mahar.error);
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    })
});
```

can anyone explain what happened here?

im learning ajax here.

Comment: You don't have `exit()` after the second `json_encode()`.

Comment: Open Chrome, press F12 then network button and look at XHR requests (at bottom there is button) and then make the request.. Look what responde do you get.. do you have returned data or you have 404?

Comment: @Jack It is not needed. The script ends there.

Comment: @PraveenKumar How do you know?

Comment: Okay, you have a point. :)

Comment: @jack, no the exit on if(empty) statement is added recently. and if there's no exit and no other statement it still work. and yes the script end there.

Comment: @Svetlio no, there's no returned data nor 404. on firebug, there's no such return value for mahar variable.

Comment: Then there's other content before the JSON, perhaps some warnings or notices. You could find out by trying to set a header; `header('Content-Type: application/json');` - it should tell you where content was already started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that the output is not (only) JSON.

Consider these statements:

```
$download = new Hijack($_POST['link']);
$download->check_link();
$download->execute();
$mahar['success'] = $download->result['success'];
$mahar['error'] = $download->result['error'];
```

Any of those statements could produce a warning or notice which would mess up the JSON syntax. You can check this by inspecting the network tab of your browser and look for the response contents.

You should resolve all the warnings your code might produce; you could also look into [logging the warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10476589#10476589) instead.

Comment: yohoo .. you are right ..

there's some warning on my class.

it's all because "" things
thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Try those 2 things..

1st. For your $_post link set full path without your domain as if it is

> http://mydomain.com/link_handler.php - put '/link_handler.php'
>
> http://mydomain.com/something/link_handler.php - put
> '/something/link_handler.php'

2nd. At your link_handler.php at first line put:

```
exit(json_encode(array('success'=>"Your request is successfull")));
```

If you get that responde at your browser then your problem is inside your PHP code..

3rd. At your jquery put 1 alert('we are posting'); before $.post to be sure that your javascripts works..

Comment: well, if i don't insert any link on input text, the if(empty) statement work well, it show error on #success.

but if i insert link on input text (and yes i make it to return error) no other message on #success

Comment: test your php code then.. does your functions works? and put exit after your second json_encode..