# Optimising a PHP web scraper to avoid 500 server errors

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm running a PHP web scraper that grabs info from online stores (disclaimer, I have permission from the stores to do this). The scraper has 3 functions:

1. Gets a list of store URLs from a JSON file (for ease, let's just say I'm passing one URL in to the function though)
2. Function `getLinks` grabs all of the links on the supplied URL page, finds the "next item" link, goes to it, grabs the product links from that page, and so on. It puts them in an array `$allLinks`.
3. I run `foreach ($allLinks as $key => $value) {getInfo($value);}`
4. Function `getInfo($value)` goes to each product URL and gets product information from each individual product page.

**Here is the full code** http://pastebin.com/SHHbG9EN#

On my server this is causing errors because (AFAIK) I'm using too much memory/the code is quite cumbersome. I can print out the results of `getLinks` just fine, but as soon as I scrape deeper I get a 500 server error (and nothing posted to the log whatsoever).

**My Question**

Should I be writing my results to mysql and will this lighten the load of the program? If so, what's the best way to do it? Do I need to (somehow) clear my variables or something to free up memory? I'm very new to PHP so the intricacies of optimising my code are foreign to me.

Comment: are you sure #item_info h2 is correct to use  because for given url, i do not see "#item_info h2". Just did  firebug conolse check for  $("#item_info h2").length and it returns 0 length.

Comment: @Shridhar Think you're looking at the wrong page, yes it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You should enable error_reporting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors","On");
```

I think you should also consider multi curl see

- [php - Fastest way to check presence of text in many domains (above 1000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891689/php-fastest-way-to-check-presence-of-text-in-many-domains-above-1000/12893559#12893559)
- [php get all the images from url which width and height >=200 more quicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035954/php-get-all-the-images-from-url-which-width-and-height-200-more-quicker/10036599#10036599)
- [How to prevent server from overloading during Curl requests in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461194/how-to-prevent-server-from-overloading-during-curl-requests-in-php/13461652#13461652)
- [php curl error handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005330/php-curl-error-handler/16066027#16066027)

Comment: He's talking about his own application creating a 500 error, not avoiding 500 errors on the pages he is scraping.

Comment: I've added that in, when there's a syntax error in the script it's writing to the log, but when it's all kosher and running as it should (and I get the 500 error) I get nothing in the log whatsoever. I'm assuming this is a memory issue, hence why I was asking about writing the data to MYSQL to (maybe?) take some load off the server