# php session_start general error handling

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm looking for a general way to handle `session_start` errors, not a way to handle one specific error. There are numerous errors which can happen, such as the session directory being full, which cause a fatal error. I want a way to trap those errors and handle them cleanly, without having to write custom handlers for each possibility.

Something like this (but not this as it doesn't work):

```
try{
    session_start();
}catch(Exception  $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

All help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10476589#10476589) on error handling in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regular PHP session functions don't throw exceptions but trigger errors. Try writing an [error handler function](http://www.php.net/manual/function.set-error-handler.php) and setting the error handler before calling `session_start`.

```
function session_error_handling_function($code, $msg, $file, $line) {
    // your handling code here
}

set_error_handler('session_error_handling_function');
session_start();
restore_error_handler();
```

However, this is just for capturing the session errors. A better way would be to create a general error handler that creates exceptions from errors and surround code parts that may throw errors with `try ... catch` blocks.