# Custom error handler function?

Tags: php

Is it possible to write a custom error handler function?

Now if there is an error on my website, then the server prints it into the result html. But I would like to create an error handler function instead.

```
function errorhandler($error) {
    echo '<span class="e">'.$error.'</span>';
}

// rest of the PHP file...
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: [Error logging, in a smooth way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331084/error-logging-in-a-smooth-way/10476589#10476589)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function. Not sure how useful this is to you.

While you want to "create an error handler function", you haven't decided what you want to do with it. I don't want to guess, but perhaps by your initial statement you mentioned that it outputs it to the HTML. You could change this output in your php.ini or at a higher level depending on your server access privileges: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php